# MS Excel pivot table for arranging and selecting attributes

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have raw data as shown in this image:
[img 1- raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttjgW.png)

I want to know how the pivot table in the image below is created:

[img 2 req pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tzxX.png)

Currently, the fields that I select are appearing as rows below one another.
[img3][3]

Comment: Your third image did not load properly. Could you please try again?

Comment: yea that was coz i had a reputation below 10, not really necessary anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Excel 2010:** Go to the "Design" tab, click the "Report Layout" dropdown, select "Show in tabular form."

Comment: so, how do i select the duration field accurately into the pivot table, coz when i select it, its breaking down to hours nad minutes seperately.